# What naming anti-patterns exist?

Tags: naming, anti-patterns

There are some names, where if you find yourself reaching for those names, you know you've already messed something up.

For example:

**XxxManager**
This is bad because a class should describe what the class does. If the most specific word you can come up with for what the class does is "manage," then the class is too big.

What other naming anti-patterns exist?

To clarify, I'm not asking "what names are bad" -- that question is entirely subjective and there's no way to answer it. I'm asking, "what names indicate overall design problems with the system." That is, if you find yourself wanting to call a component Xyz, that probably indicates the component is ill concieved. Also note here that there are exceptions to every rule -- I'm just looking for warning flags for when I really need to stop and rethink a design.

Comment: How about the [Smurf Naming Convention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2799964#2799964)?

Comment: To those voting to close as "not constructive" -- would you be willing to explain the reason why? The only one this doesn't do too well with is that the answers can be short, but it certainly meets the other five guidelines...

Comment: My problem isn't that the word "manager" is the most specific word I could use, I just have a bad habit of not thinking of a more specific term. When I say XxxManager I almost always mean XxxQueue or XxxCollection, or possibly even XxxTranslator

Comment: oh by the way http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontNameClassesObjectManagerHandlerOrData

Comment: This one depends. In C at least, the Smurf naming convention is actually a good one, because the language does not have namespaces.

Comment: I don't think it's a really unconstructive question in concept, but going by the examples so far, I think that the way it's worded, it has little to no chance of getting any constructive *answers*. This needs tightening up to invalidate the sorts of answers where people just blather on about their personal preferences.

Comment: @Aaronaught: Any suggestions? I've articulated this as well as I am able in the edit....

Comment: @jhocking - I agree with some of that link - especially that bit about "Manager" and "Handler" being too valuable to let go. And I'm not that sold on the design-pattern-based and other alternatives, which seem at least as vague in many cases. Sometimes, "Queue" or whatever may be appropriate, but often the fact that a manager keeps (or references) items in a queue is only one aspect of managing those items. Just as something useful is expressed by "manager" as a job title, IMO the same applies in OOP.

Comment: Actually I find the "manager" job title pretty vague, but that's a good thing because it gives people some flexibility in what they do. About the only thing "manager" tells me is that there are subordinates reporting to that person. I think "manager" in a class name is really only desirable until the first code refactor, because until then you aren't exactly sure what that class is doing.

Comment: @Steve: If you're doing more than just collecting the items in a single class, I think the class is too big. It should be split to be seperate bits -- one responsible for collecting the items, and one for performing operations on all the items. The most common word that *should* be used in case of Manager is Collection, but often there are other strange methods tacked on there which detract from easy understanding of what a class is for.

Comment: @Billy - one class can contain multiple others. There's no reason why a manager class shouldn't contain a queue class instance, along with other classes, instances etc to implement responsibilities of that manager. Decomposition of functionality rarely stops at a single layer.

Comment: @jhocking - that vagueness can be useful in OOP too. Requirements changes can result in changes to the specific responsibilities of a manager class, without making much (or any) difference from a callers perspective.

Answer (score 24):

The following naming anti-patterns are related to .NET and, especially, C#:

- **Inconsistencies**. If you decided to start every field name with a leading underscore, *stick to it*.
- **Ambiguos abbreviations with missing vowels**. I have seriously seen field names such as `cxtCtrlMngr`. You can hardly guess what what that is supposed to stand for.
- **Too long and verbose variable names**. `ILoginAttemptRepository` is fine and descriptive — `ILoginAttemptRepositoryUsingEntityFrameworkForObjectRelationalMapping` is descriptive, but definitely not fine.

Comment: +1 Although long, **descriptive** names are good when applied well (e.g. `EFLoginAttemptRepository : ILoginAttemptRepository` to differentiate between a repository using EF and one using, say, NHibernate), but the example you gave is just crazy.

Comment: @Wayne: Descriptive names are great! Verbose and descriptive names make their purpose clear, but are hard to read and cumbersome to use. Verbose and nonspecific names are **horrible**.

Comment: Is `I` meant to mean `interface` here, `implementer`, or first person singular? Since most classes implement an interface, having too many classes/interafes startign with an capital `I` is anoying, and hindering readability, and a code smell on it's own.

Comment: +1 for "Ambiguos abbreviations with missing vowels" those drive me crazy!

Comment: `I` clearly indicates an interface. You should avoid, if possible, to start class names with `I` and another capital letter to avoid ambiguities. (`IOStream`, for example, is an exception case.)

Comment: @Marius: That depends on language. In .NET land, that is the convention. In C++ land, it is not. (Part of that is that C++ doesn't have true interfaces) In C++, the convention to indicate an interface is usually to end the name of the class with `_base`, or prefixed with `basic`. For example, `basic_ios` or `ios_base`.

Comment: @Billy: I probably should have mentioned that I am talking about .NET and, especially, C#. Thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: @Billy ONeal: C++ has interfaces; they're just not artificially separated from classes. ;)

Comment: @Jon: No, it does not. It's not a limitation that it does not becuase it does have multiple inheritance, and it does have abstract classes. But it does not have interfaces -- there's no need for them as the C++ constructs are more powerful than interfaces are.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: That was my point.

Comment: One thing I think you should mention is that the *reason* for having too-verbose names is usually a failure to make proper use of namespacing. I'd expect to see a QN like `Acme.Security.Entities.LoginAttemptRepository`, which communicates all the same information but in a sane class name (`LoginAttemptRepository`).

Comment: Isn't `cxtCtrlMngr` pretty obviously `contextControlManager`?

Comment: @sparkleshy: Why not just write `contextControlManager`? Still, even that would be a bad name: what context? What does it control? What does it manage? Seriously, with our modern IDEs, the necessity for Hungarian Notation is gone ...

Comment: @MariusSchulz: oh yeah, I agree with you :) Just thought it wasn't such a terribly opaque abbreviation.

Answer (score 9):

One that I run into often is, simply, not using any naming pattern at all.  Typically indicative of developer ignorance (that naming patterns are a *good thing*) and also this anti-pattern tends to grossly violate SRP by stuffing all kinds of methods that are kinda/sorta related to a class into that class itself, so for instance a Customer class has properties, CRUD methods, anything remotely related to a Customer that some part of the application needs.

I'll also add that using "Engine" as a suffix is about the same as using "Manager".  It's very vague and a class called `XxxEngine` tends to be what amounts to a VB-style Module containing a bunch of methods so it's in one "easy to use" spot, without any knowledge or idea of object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 7):

Well, simple answers first: type hungarian ( http://mindprod.com/jgloss/unmainnaming.html , also has some great other ideas. A more balanced view on when hungarian is not evil, 
 http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html )

Comment: Hungarian Notation is **ALWAYS** evil :)

Comment: @Wayne: +1, true story.

Comment: @Wayne: Actually, it's not *always* evil. I worked for Charles at Xerox in the late 70's and the *original* naming system was a lifesaver. We were working in BCPL which has 1 type: integer. Everything else about type was conveyed by use and naming convention. We had 7 programmers + Charles and any one of us could walk into someone else's code and immediately be productive. This is not to say that it can't be horribly twisted/misapplied (even by Charles), just that in the right context it was the right solution.

Comment: @Peter: To be more precise — **nowadays**, Hungarian Notation is evil regarding the tools that are available by now (IntelliSense and friends).

Comment: @Wayne: Type hungarian is evil. Apps hungarian is fine.

Comment: Prefixes are an indication for a poor language or a poor IDE or both.

Comment: @Marius: Read Joel's article. The type system can't always enforce all semantic differences between variables. Intellisense doesn't help in such cases either.

Comment: @user unknown: Then I have yet to see a good language or a good IDE.

Comment: Type is easier to infer than use, esp. with modern editors. However, it requires discipline. You don't have to prefix *everything*. I work in Java, and most of the time apps Hungarian isn't necessary, but when I'm doing anything requiring several of the same type of variable (like fromX and toX) in coordinate systems it's a lifesaver.

Comment: What would be nice is a general ability to make new types easily.  "This one is like an int, except that it applies to row numbers."

Comment: @David yes a type-safe typedef makes hungarian notation (of all kinds) obsolete

Comment: @Inca: IMHO, some form of Hungarian should have been (but wasn't) used in .NET and Java to distinguish values held in unshared mutable objects, values held in objects that may not be legitimately changed (*even if their types are mutable*), identified entities, and encapsulated entities.  Which role is served by a reference is *not* a function of the reference type; indeed, even a type like `int[]` can be any of those four things.

Answer (score 7):

Speeling:

I have a leaning disability and can't spell.  With out the spell checker I am powerless I try to copy all the names I create to a word processor for verification but I always miss some.  At my last project I wrote a large part of the api and I guess I didn't spell check the first time I used the word responce and I assumed it was right because no one told me.  We had at least 50 functions with responce in it.  A new person came on the team and asked why we use responce I felt real dumb.

Comment: I used a jQuery plugin briefly where the one of the parameters was `affect` (instead of effect). It drove me crazy and I quickly found a different plugin to do the same thing.

Comment: The worst problem I have with it is that, once I see a misspelled name, it really hurts my ability to remember what the names are.

Comment: It gets worse when the same thing is spelled differently in different parts of the code. Like when you have a field strenght of class Srtength accessed by method getStrenth().

Comment: From my experience, if you are having problems like that you can easily fix it by learning Russian accent and keep saying to everyone that your first language is Russian, that would explain why you are making such mistakes. :)

Answer (score 6):

Prefixing an 'I' to the name of an interface, or 'Abstract' to the name of an abstract class. This *might* be excusable in languages that don't have the concept of abstract classes, or that don't differentiate between interfaces and abstract classes - but in Java, for example, it's always a bad idea.

Also, I don't agree with you on the Manager thing. I use that pattern sometimes, and it just means that if I tried to name it something else, then the name wouldn't be any more descriptive than XxxxxManager. There are some tasks (not necessarily complex ones) that just can't be summarized neatly in one or two words.

Comment: @Mike: I fully disagree with your statement, sorry. In my opinion, `XxxxManager` is the worst possible name a class can have. Of course it does manage something! That's the reason it was written for. `Manager` is a meaningless filler word that adds no value to understanding – by its name – what a class is responsible for.

Comment: What about, say, `TabManager`? Got a better name for a class that controls a JSP tab mechanism? Or *gasp* `TabController`... As far as prefixing with `Abstract`, I feel it's overused but is often valid (see the Java libraries for examples). I think I can safely say that I've never seen `I` interfaces in any place where someone wasn't trying to program against an interface that shouldn't have been there. Like, only one class implements the interface.

Comment: I voted this up even though .NET conventions recommend using the `I` prefix for interfaces (Why I don't know, I presume to avoid the Java situation where you have to think of a generic name *and* a specific name, or worse use the dreaded `Impl` suffix).

Comment: @Wayne: Generally you *can* avoid it. The easiest way is...don't have an interface! You don't need a `IAbstractPageFactoryImpl`. Poor design decision all around.

Comment: @Michael: I meant having say `interface PageFactory` and `class PageFactoryImpl implements PageFactory`.  Agreed that you should use naming like you suggested in Java, but the fact remains .NET encourages the `I` prefix.

Comment: @Wayne: I actually was talking about that. Sorry if I sounded like I was flamebaiting. Those "encouragements" are one big reason I don't use .Net anymore. Of course, the Java ecosystem has it's own problems too, like acronyms for everything.

Comment: @Michael: Sadly I agree, I sometimes think I'd prefer to code in Java (for reasons I've said in previous posts here, so won't rehash) but my locale is almost 100% .NET.

Comment: @Michael @Mike: The thing about anti-patterns is that there are exceptions to every rule. There may very well be cases where that name makes sense -- but I don't know of any. In the case of `TabManager` I would suggest `TabCollection`.

Comment: If I'm doing things "right" I'll see the interface name a lot more frequently than the concrete class name, which is why I prefer naming which makes the interface the most readable version. Thus my preference is to name interfaces `Foo` and implementations as `FooImpl`. I'd rather deal with `Foo` all day than with `IFoo`.

Comment: @Darien (And others): Either way -- it doesn't matter. None of those names are anti-patterns (and therefore they're off topic for this question). I don't think you can say anything about a system's design from whether or not they use `IXxx` or `XxxImpl`.

Comment: This is just totally, utterly wrong. There are *very* good reasons to visually distinguish interfaces from classes: (a) they can't be instantiated, (b) they can't be freed/disposed, (c) they can't be serialized, (d) they *can* be proxied/intercepted, etc., etc., etc.  You've just thrown out something you personally dislike (for some bizarre and unexplained reason) as an example of an anti-pattern without *any* justification at all.

Comment: @Wayne: I think .NET got its `I` convention from COM.

Comment: @Aaronaught: You forgot an even more important reason for the interface "I": interface names and class names have different semantics when applied as generic constraints.  Further, being able to guess the name of a class associated with an interface (drop the "I") is useful.  My only quibble with interface naming is that I think it should have been a lowercase "i".  An interface `iMutableFoo` would have been much more readable than `IMutableFoo`.

Comment: Whenever possible, interfaces should be preferred over concrete classes for argument types and return types.  Therefore, it makes sense for interfaces to get the "clean" names, and the concrete implementations (the actual type of which the caller may not even know or care about) to get the warts.

Comment: I completely agree. Names should not include things that programmers don't need to worry about. Knowing that something is an interface is for the compiler to worry about. You should be able to replace a concrete class with an interface and the usages should be blissfully unaware. For that matter, a terrible naming convention is to name a variable directly after its type - at least for typed languages. For typeless languages I would recommend including the type in the name always, or better yet, switch to a grown-up language. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Well I'm afraid my opinions are a little bit controversial. But lets try ...

As far as I'm concerned I have to agree with Mike Baranczak, names like XxxController, XxxHandler is something we really often use. For us a Controller is something like an entrypoint for something "encapsolated" e.g. managing transactions, dealing with unexpected errors, calling XxxHandler for doing the actual work. I would say a XxxManager is a synonym for a controller. I think its important not to use Manager in one case and Controller in an other. Being consistent is very important if you work in a team.

It would be really hard or maybe not even possible to find better names for stuff like this. Xxx should be well choosen to make the situation more clear.

What I personally do not like is, when a method called get... or set... is more than just a simple accessor. I like det... for determine.

An other thing, that comes into my mind: According to uncle Bob. An "And" in a method name is a sign of doing to much. But life is not always just black and white - there are situations where I think its ok - eg. due to performance issues (when you already have the data due to check why not process them) ...

I'm personally also a big fan of the systems hungarian notation - most of the time you are dealing with sourcecode in an IDE ok. But often you are using just an editor or you are browsing the repo in a browser. One disadvantage might be toolsupport due to type-prefixes ...

I think the most important thing is beeing consitent - a suboptimal convention - for me - is better than having no convention ...

Comment: "Controller" has different semantics than "Manager". Personally, I don't like either, but "Controller" gets by because it's a common component of many patterns, particularly MVC. XxxHandler is just as bad. If the class just "handles" something -- then either the class is too big, or it should just be called the "Xxx" part.

Comment: *"It would be really hard or maybe not even possible to find better names for stuff like this"* - not if you designed your type hierarchy properly, with well-defined dependencies and responsibilities.  Of course if you're using "Controller" as part of an MVC or "Handler" for a generic event/message handler then that's different - those are examples of *jargon* - but if they're just being used as generic names for ill-defined classes then that's a major red flag.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the worst naming anti-pattern is this one:

```
create table stuff(..., foo1 string, bar1 string,
                        foo2 string, bar2 string, 
                        foo3 string, bar3 string, ...)
```

We have a three-element list of [foo,bar] pairs.  If we need a fourth, we will have to add new columns to the table.

Leading to code like this:

```
'SELECT foo' + i + ', bar' + i + ' FROM stuff'
```

A separate table should be created with columns foo and bar and linked to the stuff table:

```
create table fubar(foo string, bar string, stuff_id long)
```

The second worst is this:

```
class Student {
  ...
  String homeStreet;
  String homeCity;
  String homeState;
  String permStreet;
  String permCity;    
  String permState;
  ...
}
```

Here we have six fields instead of two instances of an Address class.

This anti-pattern is marked by a series of two-part names listing every combination of two sets, e.g. [foo, bar] x [1,2,3] or [home, perm] x [street, city, state]

Comment: -1 -- this does not mention naming at all.

Comment: A naming anti-pattern can't include more than one name?

Comment: How does too many arguments `==` naming antipattern? I'm confused.

Comment: as far as i understand him, the convention is one that allows numbers where an actual name should be taken. These numbers lead to a false impression, that the items are some kind of list or array

Comment: @keppla: Ah, I see. I don't think these are naming anti-patterns, but they at least mention naming, so I'll remove my -1. While I think these are bad names, I don't think they indicate anything about the pattern of the design of your system.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Yes they do.  The design problem is the lack of normalization, and the number suffixes are the naming pattern pointing to it.

Answer (score 4):

Any class or interface naming that is a [tautology](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2011/02/interface-and-class-naming-anti-patterns-java-naming-convention-tautologies/) is a bad one, not just in Java which the link talks about, but in any language.

> Tautology (rhetoric), using different
>   words to say the same thing even if
>   the repetition does not provide
>   clarity.

Comment: Interesting. Any examples?

Comment: I read the link, it says "tautology"... ;)

Comment: The first rule of tautology club is the first rule of tautology club.

Comment: I read the link (okay, the *content* of the link) and found no examples

Comment: okay so according to that link we should stop using I<InterfaceName> ... right.

Comment: I don't see the damage of the I convention. It is Hungarian notation used correctly. It tells you something important about the symbol. I had trouble adjusting to Java because unbeknownst to me I was trying to instantiate interfaces, because List, something that would intuitively present a list, is an interface. Your statement is also very absolute. No room here whatsoever?

Comment: Read the linked article, and understand what tautology means. Also violates DRY Principals. Do you suffix every concrete class with `Class` or prefix it with `C`? No, doesn't make sense, waste of effort, always useless.

Answer (score 4):

I frequently encounter software libraries with generic names such as `Library` or `Common`.  They indicate suboptimal design: the developers make an effort to avoid code duplication but without any attempt to create a design decomposed on the basis of functionality.

Comment: +1 - I see "Common" all the time.

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx%5C) on naming, I can provide this list for bad names:

1. They are not semantic, which means that they have names which instead of emphasizing on what it does, emphasize on **the technology it uses** or **the pattern it's based on**.
2. They don't follow a syntactical consistency. For example, part of names are camel cased, while other part is pascal cased.
3. They are abbreviations, which are hard to understand, like **ScrollableX** instead of **CanScrollHorizontally**
4. They're chosen such that they mess with the keywords of that environment.

Comment: I actually like "ScrollableX" at least as much as "CanScrollHorizontally". "X" isn't really an abbreviation.

Comment: @user1172763 You'll like it up to the point where every co-worker asks what "X" means.