# Is having a Data Access Layer as singleton a good ideea

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, singleton

I'm working on a project(web application) where I have a `DataManager(IDALContract dalImplementation)` class that does some stuff with the data after retrieving it from the database or before saving it in the database.

My question: Is there any reason why the `IDALContract` object I'm passing in to the constructor should/should not be a singleton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [FooManager is a smell.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81981/what-naming-anti-patterns-exist) Managers invariably suffer problems because a "Manager" is a catchall that pushes it towards having [multiple responsibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). I strongly encourage you to not go down that road towards God objects.
2. [Singletons are anti-patterns.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons) ***Always.*** They force you to only ever have one object of a type, and no such thing exists. You're going to tell me that you will never, ever have more than one data access layer? You'll never need to access say, your database, a cache, or some NoSQL store at the same time? Are you *really* sure you want to limit your design that strongly?

Comment: Also, especialy bad for a web application where each request will be simultaniuously using the same DAL object